# Zend 1.12 Form w File Upload is Invalid

Tags: forms, zend-framework, file-upload

I ran into a roadblock with Zend 1.12.3 while submitting a form with file upload input. All seems to be looking just fine, but for some reason the form does not validate. However, when running getMessages() to retrieve errors, the list comes out blank. Any insights here? Thanks!

Here is my Controller:

```
public function makeOfferAction()
{
    $form   =   new Application_Form_Lawyer_MakeOffer();
        if ($this->req->isPost()) 
        {
            if ($form->isValid($this->req->getPost()))
            {
                ....
            }
        }
    }      

    $this->view->makeofferForm  =   $form;
}
```

Here is my Form:

```
class Application_Form_Index_MakeOffer extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
     $this->setMethod('post') 
            ->setAttrib('id','form-make-offer');

    $file    =   new My_File();
    $this->addElement('file', 'upload', array(
        'label'         => 'Attach Document',
        'ignore'        => true,
        'destination'   => $file->getDestinationPath(),
    ));

    $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
        'ignore'   => true,
        'label'    => 'Make Offer',
        'class'     => 'button large right'
    ));
}
}
```

Here is my View:

```
<?= $this->makeofferForm ?>
```

Also tried manually writing out the form with the same errors:

```
<form id="form-offer" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?= $this->url() ?>">
    <?= $this->makeofferForm->upload ?>
    <?= $this->makeofferForm->submit ?>
</form>
```

**UPDATE:**

Just to follow up on this, the issue was not in the form; although, form encoding does matter when dealing with file uploads. The issue was that the form was submitted via an AJAX call and that prevents file uploads as a security feature.

Comment: Please show us the error messages you receive validating your form.

Comment: Tobias, thanks for the tip, but you obviously did not read the intro to my problem: "when running getMessages() to retrieve errors, the list comes out blank"

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the form type like this:

`$this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');`

for file upload it is mandatory.

Comment: I have tried that, as well as manually writing out the form in HTML and only feeding in the field (see modified question). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your error messages. You can receive them like this:

```
   $form->getMessages();
```

Perhaps the file exceeds the max_upload_size defined in your php.ini.

Comment: No files are uploaded and the max file size is defined in the corresponding hidden field.